# Duvida de navegação

Tags: facebook, react, react-native

Criei um projeto RN e dentro dele criei uma pasta chamada **screens**.

Dentro da pasta **screens** criei os arquivos **app.js e home.js**

na index.android.js eu somente dei um: 
**import App from './screens/app';**

Na **app.js** estou utilizando o stackNavigator e dei um 
**import Home from './home'**

Na **home.js** usei: **import App from './App'**

Ao executar apresenta um erro que não é possível resolver o módulo App, na home.js.

Estou meio perdido em relação a organizar o projeto em pastas e importar e navegar entre elas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Poste foto do seu código para que o entendimento do problema seja claro.

Sobre a navegação com o StackNavigator, deixo abaixo um exemplo em meu github em que utilizo esse módulo de forma objetiva.

Link: [GitHub](https://github.com/juliofalbo/react-native-app5-navigation)

Espero ter ajudado.

Att,

Júlio Falbo

Comment: Obrigado. Irei verificar!

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente, tome cuidado com o jeito que você está organizando seus imports. Ao importar `home` dentro de `app` e `app` dentro de `home`, você está causando uma **[circular dependency](https://medium.com/content-uneditable/circular-dependencies-in-javascript-a-k-a-coding-is-not-a-rock-paper-scissors-game-9c2a9eccd4bc)**

Segundo, por acaso você está exportando algo nesses seus arquivos?

Lembre-se que ao usar `import algo from './arquivo'` você precisa ter certeza que esse outro arquivo está exportando algo. Exemplo:

*file1.js* `export default {};` -> *file2.js* `import algo from './file1'`;

*file1.js* `export { objeto1, objeto2 };` -> *file2.js* `import { objeto1, objeto2 } from '.file1'`

Comment: Obrigado amigo. Muito boa sua explanação!